# Convert data {shape+XML} format to my custom map data format {XML}

Tags: convert, xml, gml

I work with "map" represented logically as custom XML format **not** compatible with any OGC format like GML, but **roughly based on OSM XML**. Unfortunately I cannot change to work with OGC compatible known XML format.

I have data from GIS supplier: shapefile & **corresponding** XML, also **not** compatible with any OGC format (of course the shapefile is valid known format).

My task is to convert supplier data to my XML format. It's understood I have attributes not existing in the supplier's data and vice versa.

Because direct conversion from first XML format to second XML format (both are custom not well known formats) means complex piece of code basically merging XML schemas (am I correct here?). I think to apply 2 step approach - First convert to OSM and then from OSM to my format - Which again will result coding piece of code transforming known XML format (OSM) to my XML format, which will be complex task, but less complex that direct conversion (I can take advantage over exiting OSM open sourced codes). (again - am I correct here - it's inevitable down the road code some XML merger algorithm?)

So If I just try to export the shapefile to OSM (with lot's of tools out there) - It's not 100% guarantee all the data from the corresponding XML of the shapefile will be converted also, am I correct? It depends whether the supplier while generating the shapefile included into them all the data from the XML...

Comment: Does "SW" mean software or something else?  I'm assuming "DB" means database.  In general it is best to try an write out terms in full the first time you use them in your question.

Comment: @PolyGeo I edited the question

Comment: The reason for this being placed On Hold was a toss up between "too broad" for multiple questions and "unclear" for being not sure what you were trying to ask as a result. I think you should edit more to try and focus in on a single question.